# mongo spring how to sort the results based on a multiple nested array

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, sorting

I am using mongo spring to get the data from mongoDB . My document in mongodb looks like below

```
{  
   "_id":"993208_1",
   "clientId":"1",
   "searchQueryAnalysisObj":[  
      {  
         "searchKeyword":"coat",
         "searchKeywordScore":0.7,
         "searchAnalysisModifiedDate": ISODate("2018-08-20T11:53:08.228Z")
      },
      {  
         "searchKeyword":"wire",
         "searchKeywordScore":1.2,
         "searchAnalysisModifiedDate": ISODate("2018-09-20T11:53:08.228Z")
      }
   ],
   "_class":"com.client.model.MainClickStreamData"
}
```

I tried to sort the result based on searchKeywordScore descending , such that the highest value of searchKeywordScore will be in first place , This way I wanted to get just top 10 records .

So I tried as below

```
Query clientData = new Query(Criteria.where("clientId").is(clientId));
            clientData.with(new Sort(new Order(Direction.DESC, "searchKeywordScore")));     
            List<ClickNavigationBrandData> allProcessedClicks = mongoOperation.find(clientData, ClickNavigationBrandData.class);
```

But It did not work , then i tried to change

> new Order(Direction.DESC,
>   "searchQueryAnalysisObj.searchKeywordScore")));

But still the results are not in sorted order , could any one help me to solve this ?

Thanks,
Navneet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this -

```
Query clientData = new Query(Criteria.where("clientId").is(clientId));
            clientData.with(new Sort(Direction.DESC, "searchQueryAnalysisObj.searchKeywordScore"));
            clientData.limit(10);
```